# Какой способ IO использовать?

Tags: c++, вывод, io, ввод

Какой способ ввода-вывода использовать в современном коде? Насколько я понимаю, в стандартной библиотеке есть 3 способа: C-подобный, C++-потоки, C++-без потоков. Может есть ещё варианты (в т.ч. в сторонних библиотеках)? Если в разных ситуациях по-разному, то хотелось бы хотя бы по 1 примеру на каждый нестандартный способ.

Comment: Вы бы лучше уточнили - в каком контексте хотите использовать. Для учебных задач или приложений без интенсивного ввода-вывода для работы с файлами вполне сгодятся и потоки из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @user7860670 в промышленном коде, не знаю как измерить уровень интенсивности :). Про потоки знаю, а что есть для интенсивного ввода-вывода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если скорость I/O крайне критична - лучше использовать не библиотечные вызовы, а системные вызовы той операционной системы, для которой пишется программа. Потому как, все библиотечные вызовы транслируются в системные вызовы. Возможно получится оптимизировать лучше (но и возможно сделать хуже, нельзя об этом забывать);
2. Если скорость I/O несущественна - лучше использовать потоки, т.к. они наиболее удобны для программирования;
3. Библиотечные С-подобные вызовы - это некоторая середина между п.1 и п.2, чуть медленнее системных вызовов, чуть быстрее потоков.

P.S. При программировании важно всегда помнить о грамотной настройке буферизации I/O, иначе результаты между методами будут сильно разниться. Буферизация же разницу по скоростям сильно уравнивает.

А иногда удобно использовать "[отображение файлов в память](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)". Есть свои плюсы и минусы.

Answer (score 0):

Если читаете/пишете файл мелкими кусками, 100% нужна буферизация. Обычный C ввод-вывод норм, C++ надо смотреть, но может быть тоже норм. Если крупными кусками, то возможны варианты.

Если что-то сетевое-пакетное, то почти 100% лучше брать что даёт ось. На винде это может быть Alertable IO. В Linux - packet_mmap.

Потоки (которые threads, а не streams) всё это дело замедляют и усложняют. Использовать имеет смысл если приёмопередача сильно перемешана с процессорными вычислениями и однопоточный код либо выходит сложноват либо в одно ядро не влазит.